# How to run django.setup() properly from within a stand-alone python file inside of a django app (on linux-ubuntu)?

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu

Im trying to run a stand-alone python file in a django project. The problematic code is below (standalone.py):

```
import os
import django

# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings") tried as well
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproject.settings"

django.setup()
```

The error i receive is: 'No module named myproject.settings'. Somehow the project settings file is not being recognized.

The file runs just fine on my local machine however the problem occurs when running the file on a linux-ubuntu server.

This file is being run from within an app: myproject>myapp>standalone.py

When i move this file to the same directory that myproject resides in, the file runs just fine, so im assuming that the myproject.settings module is not being recognized from within the app directory.

As a temp fix:

```
sys.path.append('path_to_myproject/')
```

seems to resolve the issue, but definitely not something i want in production code. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you make a Django management command?

Comment: Thanks for the post, I read this in the docs but didn't quite understand how to apply this to my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the settings module is `myproject.settings`, then the outer `myproject` directory must be on the python path. If the script is in the outer `myproject` directory (the one that contains `manage.py`) then you don't need to do anything because the current directory is on the path. Otherwise, you have to manually add the directory to the python path.

The way to add something to the python path is `sys.path.append()`, so you can't avoid having that in production code (unless you use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable instead). Perhaps you would be happier with adding the parent directory instead of hardcoding the path.

```
sys.path.append('..')
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the post, i was looking for a way to do this. Do you think that there could be a better way? Without adding to sys.path

Comment: No, you can't avoid adding the directory to the python path. How do you expect Python to be able to import `myproject/settings.py`, if the directory containing `myproject` isn't on the Python path?

Comment: I agree, its much better than hardcoding the path although just want to make sure its the correct convention for running a stand-alone python script in django